# Project output is not moved to output folder using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I'm using [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) to compile a .py file. Whichever setting I choose, it does not work.

```
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 737, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 684, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbliekynp\main.spec", line 21, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 450, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 549, in assemble
    icon.CopyIcons(tmpnm, self.icon)
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 216, in CopyIcons
    return CopyIcons_FromIco(dstpath, [srcpath])
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 153, in CopyIcons_FromIco
    for i, f in enumerate(icons):
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 117, in __init__
    entry.fromfile(file)
  File "c:\users\benbe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 76, in fromfile
    self._fields_ = list(struct.unpack(self._format_, data))
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 16 bytes
```

Project output will not be moved to output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a older-version of python try python 3.8.10

Install python 3.8.10 now go to the directory where it is installed and go inside the script folder and open cmd there and type pip install auto-py-to-exe then opy your code file and paste it in the script folder of python 3.8.10 and then open cmd there and type auto-py-to-exe and then try to make the exe.

make sure your cmd is opened in the script directory

If it still does not work try it using the module pyinstaller in python 3.8.10 here you can know details about making a exe [In this link you will see how to make a exe with pyinstaller module](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/)
or you can try using cx_freeze module [here is a link for it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-cx_freeze-python/) or if you want to see a tutorial search in youtube or [you can go to this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoHWJV8iVTQ) [or this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UjlIWNMxJA)

Comment: i installed python 3.8.8

Comment: Then try any other python module to create exe